# Copying elements inside nodeset

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to copy elements from inside an nodeset and structure them in the ouput as shown.

```
<Details>
<ContractType>
<ID>001</ID>
<Name>
<FirstName>Mano</FirstName>
<Initial>1</Initial>
</Name>
</ContractType>
</Details>
```

Output:

```
<PartyDetails>
<ID>001</ID>
<Name>
<FirstName>Mano</FirstName>
<Initial>1</Initial>
</Name>
</PartyDetails>
```

Below snippet in the XSLT I tried, it doesnt actually copy the elements as I needed. What change I need to do here to strip ContractType and rename Details as shown in output.

```
    <xsl:template match="ContractType">
    <xsl:element name="PartyDetails">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:element>
       </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Your attempted XSLT shows `<xsl:template match="ns:ContractType">` - but there's no `ns:ContractType` in your input. Please read this carefully: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @michael.hor257k - My query is completely different. I am not querying how to rename it, as I already got that. I am checking how I can skip the extra element in middle, by X-Path or apply-templates. If you still feel, its against forum rules, let me know, I will remove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It **is** the same answer as the one you have received here:[Renaming node in XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462793/renaming-node-in-xml)

**If you have started with the *identity transform* template**, then your default behavior is to copy everything *as is*. Then you need to add exception rules for any nodes that need to be modified **in any way**.

For example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!-- rename Details -->
<xsl:template match="Details">
    <PartyDetails>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </PartyDetails>
</xsl:template>

<!-- remove ContractType wrapper-->
<xsl:template match="ContractType">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your example, the result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PartyDetails>
  <ID>001</ID>
  <Name>
    <FirstName>Mano</FirstName>
    <Initial>1</Initial>
  </Name>
</PartyDetails>
```